# How create basic authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, wsdl, networkcredentials

```
[SoapRpcMethod("http://email:password@api-new.begun.ru/index.php?class=AdvertiserService#getProfile", RequestNamespace = "http://email:password@api-new.begun.ru/index.php", ResponseNamespace = "http://email:password@api-new.begun.ru/index.php", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
[return: XmlElement("getProfileReturn")]
public UserProfile getProfile()
{ 
    this.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password"); // I need basic authication
    object[] results = this.Invoke("getProfile", new object[0]);
    return ((UserProfile)(results[0]));
}
```

I checked through the fidller2 Authenticate: Basic is not set

most interesting is that in the same class, so at this point everything is fine:

```
 [SoapRpcMethodAttribute("http://email:password@api-new.begun.ru/index.php?class=AdvertiserService#auth", RequestNamespace = "http://email:password@api-new.begun.ru/index.php", ResponseNamespace = "http://email:password@api-new.begun.ru/index.php", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
 [return: XmlElement("authReturn")]
 public bool auth(string login, string password, string clientLogin)
 {
    this.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
    object[] results = this.Invoke("auth", new object[] {
                                                         login,
                                                         password,
                                                         clientLogin});
    return ((bool)(results[0]));
 }
```